# ObservableCollection Refresh View MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an ObservableCollection bound to a ListBox.  Selecting an item in the list box populates a user control with it's own viewmodel based on the selected item.  I am using a Linq to SQL DataContext for getting data from my model to the viewmodels.

The problem is that the displaymember for the listbox is bound to a property that combines two fields, a number and a date, for the item.  The usercontrol allows the user to change the date, and I want that to be reflected in the list box immediately.

I initialize the collection and add in CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged handlers so that the collection is listening for the changes to properties within the collection:

```
public void FillReports()
{
    if (oRpt != null) oRpt.Clear();
    _oRpt = new ViewableCollection<Reportinformation>();
    //oRpt.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged; //<--Don't need this
    foreach (Reportinformation rpt in _dataDc.Reportinformations.Where(x => x.ProjectID == CurrentPrj.ID).OrderByDescending(x => x.Reportnumber))
    {
        oRpt.Add(rpt);
    }
}

private void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged rpt in e.OldItems)
            {
                rpt.PropertyChanged -= item_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged rpt in e.NewItems)
            {
                rpt.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void item_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = sender.GetType().ToString();
    if(s.Contains("Reportinformation"))
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("oRpt"); //This line does get called when I change the date
    else if (s.Contains("Observation"))
    {
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("oObs");
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("oObsByDiv");
    }
}
```

The date gets changed correctly and the change persists and is written back to the database, but the change does not reflect in the listbox unless I actually change the collection (which happens when I switch jobs on another control in the same window as the listbox).  The line in my property changed handler raises the change event for "oRpt" which is the observable collection bound to the ListBox, and changing the date does call the handler as verified with the debugger:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lsbReports" ItemsSource="{Binding oRpt}" DisplayMemberPath="ReportLabel" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRpt}" 
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="170" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
```

But it seems that simply raising that change doesn't actually trigger the view to refresh the "names" of the items in the listbox.  I have also tried to Raise for the ReportLabel bound to the DisplayMemberPath, but that doesn't work (worth a try though).  I'm not sure where to go from here, as I think it's bad practice to reload the oRpt collection based on changing the date (therefore the name) of one of the actual items as I expect this database to grow fairly quickly.

Here is the Reportinformation extension class (this is an auto generated LinqToSQL class, so just my part is below):

```
public partial class Reportinformation // : ViewModelBase <-- take this out INPC already hooked up
{
    public ViewableCollection<Person> lNamesPresent { get; set; }
    public string ShortDate
    {
        get
        {
            DateTime d = (DateTime)Reportdate;
            return d.ToShortDateString();
        }
        set
        {
            DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(value);
            if (d != Reportdate)
            {
                Reportdate = DateTime.Parse(d.ToShortDateString());
                SendPropertyChanged("ShortDate");//This works and uses the LinqToSQL call not my ViewModelBase call
                SendPropertyChanged("ReportLabel"); //use the LinqToSQL call
                 //RaisePropertyChangedEvent("ReportLabel"); //<--This doesn't work
            }
        }
    }

    public string ReportLabel
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Reportnumber, ShortDate);
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("oRpt");
    }

    public string RolledNamesString
    {
        get
        {
            if (lNamesPresent == null) return null;
            return string.Join("|",lNamesPresent.Where(x=>x.Name!= "Present on Site Walk").Select(x=>x.Name).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

ANSWER

So my mistake was that I was adding to the LinqToSQL partial classes, and was using my ViewModelBase there which reimplements all of the INPC stuff over top of the autogenerated partial class.  I undid that, and just use the INPC from the autogenerated designer stuff and it all works as expected.  Thanks to SledgeHammer for chatting and making me rethink all of this!

Comment: The `Reportinformation` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise it for `ReportLabel` whenever the computed value of `ReportLabel` changes

Comment: Please give the code for the `Reportinformation` class

Comment: @DaveM See my edit.  I am doing what you suggest will work but raising the change to the property that the DisplayMemberPath is bound to does not make a difference.

Comment: After some more poking and trials in the ViewModel, I have verified that even adding a new element and then Raising the property changed event for "oRpt" does not update the list.  The only thing that does is calling FillReports from my item_PropertyChanged handler, which just seems too heavy handed.

Comment: @PaulGibson you shouldn't need to do any of that. Use ObservableCollectionT and T should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and if you are binding properly and INPC is properly implemented, all the updates should be handled auto-magically. Your "this does not work" line should do exactly what you are trying to do... and you shouldn't need to manually subscribe to events.

Comment: @PaulGibson Upon closer inspection, I think I see why its not working as you expect... see my original comment, you shouldn't need to do any of the manual subscribe / unsubscribe... your issue is that you are not allowed to overwrite _oRpt. WPF expects it to be the same instance throughout the lifetime of the window. FillReports news up a new one and is whats breaking everything. You should only do the minimal operations on the list to sync it up (add/remove)… no clear or new's...

Comment: @SledgeHammer I agree that it should work, but it doesn't.  I'm trying to figure out why, and suspect that it has something to do with the LinqToSQL classes that are auto-generated.

Comment: @PaulGibson, see my 2nd comment, you aren't allowed to change the instance of the collection, that's whats breaking it...

Comment: @SledgeHammer I see your second comment.  I added FillReports to my handler as a way to get it to work (and it does work, by changing the collection and then raising the change property).  But I agree that this should not be necessary, and is not the best way.  This is the only way I've gotten the list to refresh though.  FillReports should only be the initialization of the collection ideally.

Comment: @PaulGibson well, it's not REALLY going to work and you'll have side effects... I.e. when you refresh, the user will lose focus on the list and scroll position, etc. I'd strip it back down and try again from the basics... its how WPF is supposed to work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179660/discussion-between-paul-gibson-and-sledgehammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this one of two ways. Either your `ReportInformation` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the property changed events for the `ReportLabel` property whenever it changes:

```
public class ReportInformation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _numberField;
    private DateTime _dateField;

    public int NumberField
    {
        get => _numberField;
        set 
        {
            if (_numberField != value)
            {
                _numberField = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ReportLabel));
            }
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateField
    {
        get => _dateField;
        set
        {
            if (_dateField != value)
            {
                _dateField = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ReportLabel));
            }
        }
    }

    public string ReportLabel => $"{NumberField}: {DateField}";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

OR, you can use in your `ListBox` an `ItemTemplate` rather than `DisplayMemberPath` like so:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbReports" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding oRpt}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentRpt}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberField}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DateField}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave . . . The Reportinformation class is an autogenerated LinqToSQL class, and I have expanded it to add the label that basically does what you are doing in the template.  So, I was thinking that the actual properties for this class are all handled (getters and setters) and that I can't overload them.   The label class is just a getter, with no way to set since it just returns a combo of two fields.  I have added my extension to the Reportinformation class to my post above.

Comment: This is the right answer, and what I thought I was doing.  However the LinqToSQL designer classes already implement the INPC stuff, and when I extended to derive from my ViewModelBase I am reimplementing it which I think breaks the functionality.  So I took that out and changed the call per my edits which then works.